# NGINX docker container cannot be accessed in the web browser

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, devops

I have deployed this docker container.

```
docker container run -d -p 8080:80 --name my-nginx2 --network my-net nginx:latest
```

When I do a `curl localhost:8080`, I  am able to access it. However, when I type in my `<public-address>:8080` it is not working. I cannot access it on the web browser.

I am running a red hat 8 ec2 instance on AWS. My security group looks like this. I am not sure if this should be something related with SG.

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to the image you shared, you are only allowing traffic on ports 80 and 22;

When you execute the docker run command with the `-p :8080:80` option, you are basically telling your instance to listen on 8080 and forward the traffic to the container on port 80;

You have two options:
Start the container using the `-p 80:80` option, hence port 80 is already allowed, then try to access your web-app in the browser at `<instance-external-ip-address>:80`

The second option is to add a firewall rule to allow ingress on port `8080` and then access your web-app in the browser at `<instance-external-ip-address>:8080`

Comment: Every time that I need to expose a port, I need to create an INBOUND security group rule allowing traffic to communicate to that port, right?

Comment: Yes. `-p <src>:<dst>` creates a DNAT rule on your instance, basically forwarding everything that incomes on the `instance:<src>`, to the `container:<dst>`. The VPC firewall is independent and has to allow inbound traffic to the instance on the <src> port

Comment: You're welcomed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers